# Rust - Is it possible to test whether Enum variants are sequential without assigning each variant a value?

Tags: rust, enums

Is there a way to tell if Enum variants are directly sequential without assigning a value to each? For instance, I am trying to see if a poker hand is a straight and want to see if all five cards are in sequential value.

```
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Hash, Copy, Clone, Debug)]
enum CardNumber {
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace,
}

fn is_sequential(card1, card2) {
     card2 == card1 + 1 // pseudo code, function I'm looking for goes here.
}

use CardNumber::*;
let cards = [Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace];
let is_sequential: bool = cards
    .windows(2)
    .all(|(card1, card2)| is_sequential(card1, card2));
```

In order to compare whether variants are sequential, do I need to add a value to each variant, or is there another function that does this?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/enumerations.html describes the default discriminant assignment of enumerations without fields.  You can just cast a fieldless enum to an integer type.

Comment: Rust enums like this have [well defined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/enumerations.html#custom-discriminant-values-for-fieldless-enumerations) discriminants. Specifically, `Two` will be `0isize`, `Three` will be `1isize`, and so on, in ascending order as they are defined. You can simply cast the enum variant as in `card1 as isize` and compare the integers.

Comment: @user2722968 that worked. Thanks!

Comment: You don't even need a value to compare whether variants are sequential. Since your enum derives `PartialOrd`, you can just compare them with `<`, order them with `sort()` etc.